# Python multiprocessing won't work

Tags: python

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
x=None

def pp():
    global x
    x=MyClass()
    x.start()

def main():
    global x
    p=Process(target=pp)
    p.start()
    while x==None:
        print("Not yet...")
    while 1:
        print(x.getoutput(),end="")
    p.join()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

The x.start() method opens a TKInter window, so it runs forever (or at least until the user closes the window). I'm trying to run another process that would get information from the used window, but it doesn't work.

How can i make it work?

Comment: If this is only to make functiional things rather than speed things up, you probably want to use threads which share memory with the original thread. Processes a bit less simple to handle.

Comment: does it make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the first thing to point out here is that each child process will import the main script and have it's own local copy. It's not possible to use global variables in the way you're trying to here, because the child processes don't use the same namespace. If you're set on using multiprocessing for this, you need to use a communication pipe of some description, as described in the following documentation:

http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html#multiprocessing-queues

I am a little curious what your ultimate objective is here for using multiprocessing. Still, if you really want to do it, it's possible:

```
import multiprocessing
import tkinter
import time

def worker(q):
    #q is a queue for communcation.
    #Set up tkinter:
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    localvar = tkinter.StringVar()
    wind = tkinter.Entry(root,textvariable=localvar)
    wind.grid()

    #This callback puts the contents of the entry into the queue
    #when the entry widget is modified
    def clbk(name,index,mode,q=q):
        q.put(localvar.get())
    localvar.trace_variable('w',clbk)

    #Some window dressing that will signal to the main process that 
    #the window has been closed
    def close(root=root,q=q):
        q.put('EXIT')
        root.destroy()
        root.quit()
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",close)
    root.mainloop()

def main():
    #Make a queue to facilitate communication:
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker,args=(queue,))
    p.start()

    #Wait for input...
    while True:
        ret = queue.get()
        print(ret)
        if ret=='EXIT':
            break
        time.sleep(0.1)
    #Finally, join the process back in.
    p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Ignoring the window dressing, that will now print text entered into your tkinter entry widget, and exits when the window is closed.

Comment: Is it really that complicated? Well whatever, you mentioned it can be done without multitasking, how so?

Comment: Nevermind it works now. In order to not be like that xkcd comic said: i used a queue between MyClass and main() in order to get the output

Comment: It depends what your intention is here - if all you wanted was a popup window then I suggest that a tkinter.Toplevel object is more what you should be looking at; it's difficult to be any more informative without knowing why you want to do multiprocessing here. If the key was instead to be able to monitor the user input, then an entry widget with a tkinter variable and a trace_variable as described in the example would allow you to call a function whenever the variable is modified.